# POST http://domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I've set up a form that sends data to a database table using AJAX, but I'm getting a "400 Bad Request" error when submitting the form.

Here's my setup:

I have a form in my WordPress site that collects user information (first name, last name).
When the form is submitted, the data is sent via AJAX to a PHP function (add_address) defined in my child theme's `functions.php` file.
The PHP function is supposed to sanitize and insert the data into a custom database table (pl_addresses).
Here's the relevant code:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_add_address', 'add_address');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_address', 'add_address');

function add_address()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Sanitize input data
    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['address-firstname']);
    $lastname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['address-lastname']);
    

    // Prepare and execute SQL query using prepared statements
    $wpdb->insert(
        'pl_addresses',
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
        ),
        array(
            '%s', '%s'
        )
    );
}
```

This is JavaScript code in `.js` file:

```js
jQuery('#add_address_form').on('submit', function () {
    var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();

    form_data.push({ "name": "security", "value": ajax_nonce });

    console.log('Form data:', form_data); 
    console.log('AJAX URL:', ajax_url);    

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_url, 
        type: 'post',
        data: form_data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('AJAX Response:', response);
            alert(response);
        },
        fail: function (err) {

            console.error("There was an error: " + err); 
            alert("There was an error: " + err);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This HTML form:

```html
<form id="add_address_form" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal form-control-borderless display-none">
    <h4 class="sub-header"><i class="gi gi-home"></i><span>Pridėti pristatymo adresą</span></h4>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" id="address-firstname" name="address-firstname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Vardas *" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" id="address-lastname" name="address-lastname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Pavardė *" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-actions col-md-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right" style="width:auto;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Užregistruoti</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also have this code in head tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>';
    var ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("secure_nonce_name"); ?>';
</script>
```

And i get such error:

[image]

I've confirmed that the AJAX URL and nonce are correctly set. However, when I submit the form, I receive a "400 Bad Request" error in the console, and the AJAX request fails.

What could be causing this issue? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to pass the [action](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#data) parameter with your AJAX call, hence 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You missed   `action: 'add_address'`

```
jQuery('#add_address_form').on('submit', function () {
    var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();

    form_data.push({ "name": "security", "value": ajax_nonce });

    console.log('Form data:', form_data); 
    console.log('AJAX URL:', ajax_url);    

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_url, 
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'add_address',
            formdata: form_data
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('AJAX Response:', response);
            alert(response);
        },
        fail: function (err) {

            console.error("There was an error: " + err); 
            alert("There was an error: " + err);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```